# Shiny R Unique Field Values as Dropdown Items

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to create the selectInput dropdown list from the unique values of a field i.e. without having to enumerate them all. How does one do that?

For instance, in this trivial example if I had the following data.frame, state_data:

```
State  V1
MA     1   
MA     2
MA     54
VA     1 
NC     4
VA     4 
NC     20
```

I would want the dropdown options to be MA,VA,NC and then on the server side I would want it to correspond to that selected subset of the data.frame.

**UI.r**

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
headerPanel("State Data"),


sidebarPanel(
selectInput("variable","State:",
list(State)),

),


 mainPanel()


))
```

**Server.r**

```
library(shiny)


state_data <- read.csv("dummy.csv",header=T)
State <- factor(state_data$state)
State <- levels(State)


shinyServer(function(input, output) {



})
```

Comment: look at this, dynamic UI http://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/#dynamic-ui

Answer (score 3):

Here goes an example of listing csv files in a directory to form the dropdown menu-

```
filenames<-list.files(pattern="\\.csv$")

  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(inputId = "dataset",
                label = "Select",
                filenames),
```

Hope it helps